# NSCollectionView Scrolling not working right

Tags: swift, scroll, nscollectionview

I try to scroll to the newly inserted item (here called "Wert 12") in my `parameterCollectionView`. But somehow the scrolling position is just ignoring the last item. Using `NSCollectionViewScrollPosition.trailingEdge` should show the last item but it does not.

> Scroll so that the trailing edge of the selected items’ bounding box is adjacent to the trailing edge of the collection view’s bounds.

my code:

```
    parameterCollectionView.reloadData()
    let section = 0
    let item = parameterCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) - 1 //<-- last item in collection view
    let myIndexPath: Set = [IndexPath(item: item, section: section)]
    parameterCollectionView.scrollToItems(at: myIndexPath, scrollPosition: NSCollectionViewScrollPosition.trailingEdge)
```

interesting is: when selecting the item before the last via code nothing changes. So, the last item is somehow ignored:

```
parameterCollectionView.reloadData()
let section = 0
let item = parameterCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) - 2 // second last item in collection view
let myIndexPath: Set = [IndexPath(item: item, section: section)]
parameterCollectionView.scrollToItems(at: myIndexPath, scrollPosition: NSCollectionViewScrollPosition.trailingEdge)
```

So both code snippets will produce the same behavior to the collection view: Last Item ("Wert 12") Not Shown!!!

[image]

Why is `NSCollectionView` so bitchy to me all the time???

Comment: try NSCollectionViewScrollPosition.right , see if this works.

Comment: nope! I tried everything. The issue is somehow related to something else. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I'll think there is a bug in the NSCollectionView scrollToItems(at:) method. Sometimes the NSCollectionView ignores the fact that it needs to scroll, even if the above method is invoked. In such cases the items that were subject to be "scrolled in" stays outside the NSCollectionView's visible frame.

Thus, the corresponding NSCollectionViewItems can't be retrieved by e.g. invokation of the item(at:) method. In these cases item(at:) will return nil instead of a valid item reference.